# Using two useEffect but component is returning after executing first one only

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, use-effect

Here on rendering (inside return() of the Rides component), ride.distance is undefined but when in second useEffect inside map function on printing each ride they have ride.distance some value and not defined

Is the component renders after execcuting the first useEffect and the second useEffect runs later or there is some other issue?

how do is achieve that, before rendering the second useEffect completes execution ?

```
import Navbar from "./Navbar";

const Rides = () => {
  const [rides, setRides] = useState([]);
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});
  const [updatedRides, setUpdatedRides] = useState([]);


  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchRides = async () => {
      const data = await fetch('https://assessment.api.vweb.app/rides');
      const json = await data.json();
      setRides(json);
      console.log(json);
    }

    const fetchUser = async () => {
      const data = await fetch('https://assessment.api.vweb.app/user');

      const json = await data.json();
      console.log(json);
      setUser(json);
    }
    
    const makeNetworkCalls = async() => {
      await fetchRides();
      await fetchUser();
    }

    makeNetworkCalls().catch((e) => {
      console.log(e);
    })

  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    const calculateDistance = async(path, user_station) => {
      let min = Math.abs(user_station - path[0]);
      for(let i = 0; i<path.length; i++){
        if(path[i] === user_station){
          return 0;
        }
        if(Math.abs(path[i] - user_station) < min){
          min = Math.abs(path[i] - user_station);
        }
      }
      return min;
    }

    const updaterides = async() => {
      setUpdatedRides(rides);

      updatedRides.map(async(ride) => {
        ride.distance = await calculateDistance(ride.station_path, user.station_code);
        console.log(ride);
      })
    }

    updaterides().catch((e) => {
      console.log(e);
    })

  }, [rides]);

  return(
    <div>
      <Navbar user = {user}/>
      <div className="rides">
        {updatedRides.map((ride) => {
          return (
            <div className="rideDetail">
              <img src = {ride.map_url} alt="Ride_map" />
              <div>
                <p>Ride Id : {ride.id}</p>
                <p>Origin Station : {ride.origin_station_code}</p>
                <p>Station Path : {ride.station_path}</p>
                <p>Date : {ride.date}</p>
                <p>Distance : {ride.distance}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  )

}

export default Rides;
```

Comment: `useEffect`s do not run until **after** the first time the component is rendered.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed your code check it out here https://codesandbox.io/embed/busy-payne-qiiw5r?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark . Problem was related with non `async` behaviour. In your second `useEffect` inside `updaterides` function, you are setting `updatedRides` then you are mapping it but it does not work as you expected since `state` changes are not updating immediately before `map`.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Rides = () => {
  const [rides, setRides] = useState([]);
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});
  const [updatedRides, setUpdatedRides] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchRides = async () => {
      const data = await fetch("https://assessment.api.vweb.app/rides");
      const json = await data.json();
      setUpdatedRides(json);
      setRides(json);
    };

    const fetchUser = async () => {
      const data = await fetch("https://assessment.api.vweb.app/user");
      const json = await data.json();
      setUser(json);
    };

    const makeNetworkCalls = async () => {
      await fetchRides();
      await fetchUser();
    };

    makeNetworkCalls().catch((e) => {
      console.log(e);
    });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const calculateDistance = async (path, user_station) => {
      let min = Math.abs(user_station - path[0]);
      for (let i = 0; i < path.length; i++) {
        if (path[i] === user_station) {
          return 0;
        }
        if (Math.abs(path[i] - user_station) < min) {
          min = Math.abs(path[i] - user_station);
        }
      }
      return min;
    };

    const updaterides = async () => {
      setUpdatedRides(rides);

      updatedRides.map(async (ride) => {
        ride.distance = await calculateDistance(
          ride.station_path,
          user.station_code
        );
        console.log(ride);
      });
    };

    if (updatedRides?.length > 0 && rides?.length > 0) {
      updaterides().catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
      });
    }
  }, [rides, updatedRides]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="rides">
        {rides?.map((ride) => (
          <div className="rideDetail">
            <img src={ride.map_url} alt="Ride_map" />
            <div>
              <p>Ride Id : {ride.id}</p>
              <p>Origin Station : {ride.origin_station_code}</p>
              <p>Station Path : {ride.station_path}</p>
              <p>Date : {ride.date}</p>
              <p>Distance : {ride.distance}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Rides;
```

Comment: Code still looks wrong to me. `setUpdatedRides(rides)` isn't synchronous, so you can't just go and map over the rides right away as if they were updated. The mapping should happen first (with `Promise.all` or a `for` loop that doesn't use callbacks, which keeps the promises in the same chain), then the updating. `ride.distance = ...` mutates state, which is a no-no in React.

Comment: Code is not written in so good way, third state looks unnecessary but since I do not know the story behind I just fixed the code from question. For being sure both states updated in api call, I added control in second useEffect in my edit. I agree part of state mutating @ggorlen